# Headers not showing in table using qwraps2::summary_table

Tags: r, summary

I am creating a summary table for a data set I am working on.
Using the qwraps2 package, I used this code to create the table:

```
baseline_all <- 
  list(Age = 
         list("min age"         = ~ min(age),
              "mean age (sd)"    = ~ mean_sd(age, denote_sd = "paren"),
              "median age (IQR)" = ~ median_iqr(age),
              "max age"         = ~ max(age)),
       BMI =
         list("min BMI:"         = ~ min(BMI),
              "mean BMI (sd)"    = ~ mean_sd(BMI, denote_sd = "paren"),
              "median BMI (IQR)" = ~ median_iqr(BMI),
              "max BMI"         = ~ max(BMI)),
         Gender =
         list("Male"         = ~ n_perc0(gender == 1),
              "Female"       = ~ n_perc0(gender == 2)))
        baseline_table <- summary_table(combi_baseline, baseline_all)
```

This creates a table, however the headers (age, BMI, gender) are not displayed when I go and inspect it with view(baseline_table).

I have seen a question for this on Stack Overflow, but I do not understand their reasoning
What code do I need to display the headers?

[image]

Comment: Please share your complete code and data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: The data is a large dataframe, but the important thing is that it contains the variables I mention in the list code: age, BMI, Gender. What code would you like to see?

Comment: The outcome for me seems to come to this: Using the qwraps2 package, you need to insert your code into an Rmarkdown document to see the desired output.